# Java code logic

Tags: java

New to Java and using old MIT  course to self teach. Here's my code. It returns Thomas: 273
John: 243
Can anyone explain why it's returning two values rather than just the fastest runner?

```
public class Marathon {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James",
                "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
        int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };
        int smallest = times[0]; // sets smallest to 341

        for (int x = 0; x < times.length; x++) {

            if (times[x] < smallest) {
                smallest = times[x];
                System.out.println(names[x] + ": " + times[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you print something whenever you find somebody that was faster then the up to now fastest.

Comment: Because as you iterate, 273 is the *smallest when you're only looking at 341 and 273*. Then 243 is the smallest when you look at its preceding elements. Print the fastest at the end when you've iterated through all elements.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: And please note: you expect us to spend our time to help you with your homework. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly indent all of your code - and to clearly describe expected and actual behavior.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are printing everytime you find a smaller value:

```
if (times[x] < smallest) {
    smallest = times[x];
    System.out.println(names[x] + ": " + times[x]); // print always
}
```

If you need to print only fastest, than you need to separate logic to find fastest and print the result.

```
int smallest = times[0]; // sets smallest to 341
for (int x = 0; x < times.length; x++) {
    if (times[x] < smallest) {
        smallest = times[x];
    }
}
System.out.println(names[smallest] + ": " + times[smallest]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you output each time you find something that is smaller than "smallest".

You initialise smallest with first value in the times array, which is 341. Then on the first step of the loop it will be update from 341 to 243 and hence you will print Thomas.

Instead, you have to print after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have done it, you are printing every occurrence of when the if condition occurs which would be twice one for 273 and one for 243.

With this extra variable used you are saving the index at which the smallest was found and then accessing it from that. There are many ways of doing it though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James",
        "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
   int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };
   int smallest = times[0]; // sets smallest to 341
   int index = 0;

   for (int x = 0; x < times.length; x++) {

       if (times[x] < smallest) {
           smallest = times[x];
           index = x;
       }
   }

   System.out.println(names[index] + ": " + times[index]);
}
```